# Как добавить новую запись к таблице, извлеченной из базы данных java?

Tags: java, arraylist

Возможно ли добавить новую запись(нового пользователя) в таблицу, которую извлекли из базы данных? 
При нажатии кнопки должны открываться поля для ввода данных и кнопка для их сохранения! Использую jsf, данные выводятся в xhtml страницу.
Подскажите, пожалуйста! Все ли понятно я поясняю!?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Методы для добавления и сохранения новых данных: (myList- новый ArrayList; Values - класс, содержащий setters & getters. C новым списком все открывается и добавляется, но как объединить myList c getAllUsers(),если я правильно объясняю?

```
    public void addNewUser(){
        Values newValue = new Values();
        newValue.setEditable(true);
        myList.add(newValue);
        }

    public void saveNewUser(){
        System.out.println("We're in saveNewUser()");
        for(Values value: myList){
            addUser();
            value.setEditable(false);
        }
    }
```

Метод, который извлекает данные из базы данных:

```
public ArrayList<Values> getAllUsers(){
    ArrayList<Values> usersList= new ArrayList<>();
    SQL= "SELECT id,orderNo,productName,price,qty FROM Registration";
    System.out.println("Retreive values from Registration table...");
    databaseConnection();
    try {
        prepStatement= connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
        resultSet= prepStatement.executeQuery();
        boolean found= false;
        while (resultSet.next()== true) {
            Values allValues= new Values();
              allValues.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
              allValues.setOrderNo(resultSet.getString("orderNo"));
              allValues.setProductName(resultSet.getString("productName"));
              allValues.setPrice(resultSet.getBigDecimal("price"));
              allValues.setQty(resultSet.getInt("qty"));
              usersList.add(allValues);
              found= true;
        }
          resultSet.close();
          prepStatement.close();
          if (found) {
            return usersList;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error in getAllUsers()-->"+e.getMessage());
    }finally {
        close(connection);
    }
    return (null);
}

    public List<Values> getInformation(){
    return getAllUsers();
}
```

Comment: а почему не используете Hibernate или другой ORM?

Answer (score 0):

Создайте еще один метод addUser, в котором вы будете обращаться к БД и записывать значение в таблицу БД

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то лучше передавать в метод `getAllUsers()` список `myList`, и уже его заполнять данными из выборки:

```
public ArrayList<Values> getAllUsers(ArrayList<Values> usersList) {
    usersList = new ArrayList<Values>();
    ...
    return usersList;
}
```

И где-то этот метод вызывать:

```
myList = getAllUsers(myList);
```

Только нужно учесть, что `myList` будет пересоздаваться заново старые данные пропадут, что в принципе логично -- ведь он заполниться записями из выборки.